# Is VirtualHost Entry Required for CNAME Pointing to Same DocumentRoot?

Tags: apache-2.2, domain-name-system, virtualhost, cname-record, shared-hosting

> www.example.com.  1800    IN  CNAME   example.com.
>
> other.example.com. 1800    IN  CNAME   example.com.

Which method is correct in Apache when all entries point to the exact same DocumentRoot?

Would the following method work?

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        DocumentRoot "/some/place/"
        ServerName example.com
</VirtualHost>
```

OR I shall create an VirtualHost entry for each CNAME?

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        DocumentRoot "/some/place/"
        ServerName example.com
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
        DocumentRoot "/some/place/"
        ServerName www.example.com
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
        DocumentRoot "/some/place/"
        ServerName other.example.com
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your first method would not work reliable (only if it is the default VirtualHost).
Your second method will work but duplicates configuration - something you generally want to avoid.

You could use `ServerAlias` (http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#serveralias) instead:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        DocumentRoot "/some/place/"
        ServerName example.com
        ServerAlias www.example.com other.example.com
</VirtualHost>
```